# magento do not display title and logo when manufacturer attribute is set to empty

Tags: php, magento

I am working with the following codes for Magento inside product page view.phtml.

```
 <div class="manufacturer">                                                             
    <?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') == "Bellazza" || "Della" || "Pet Zone" || "Spyder Auto" ):?> 
        <div class="dealer">
            <p>Authorized Dealer:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="logoImg">
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('manufacturer/manufacturer')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('manufacturer/product_manufacturer.phtml')->toHtml();?>
        </div>
    <?php elseif ?>

    <?php endif;?>

</div>
```

So I create `div.manufacturer` to display associated brand logo image started by the title "Authorized Dealer". It works. But not all products have a brand so when I set the manufacturer attribute to empty ( refer to the image below ) I don't need the title "Authorized Dealer" anymore. What is the best practice to approach the `elseif`. Thank you

[image]

**manufacturer/manufacturer.phtml**

```
<?php
$maufacturers = Mage::getModel('manufacturer/manufacturer')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status',Array('eq'=>1));    
$_columnCount=4;
$i=0;
?>
<div class="manufacturer-list">
<?php foreach($maufacturers as $manufacturer): ?>
<?php if(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')->setAttribute(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product',"manufacturer")))->getOptionText($manufacturer->getMenufecturerName())): ?>
<?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
<ul>
<?php endif; ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=".$manufacturer->getMenufecturerName() ?>">
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setmanufacturerimage($manufacturer->getFilename())->setlegend($manufacturer->getLegend())->setListPageFlag(1)->setTemplate('manufacturer/manufacturer_resize.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
        </a>
        <div class="manufacturer-name">
            <?php echo Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')->setAttribute(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product',"manufacturer")))->getOptionText($manufacturer->getMenufecturerName()) ?>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 && $i!=count($maufacturers)): ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

**product_manufacturer**

```
<?php     
$product=$this->getProduct();
if(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')->setAttribute(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product',"manufacturer")))->getOptionText($product->getData('manufacturer'))):
    $manufacturers=Mage::getModel('manufacturer/manufacturer')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('menufecturer_name',$product->getData('manufacturer'));
    foreach($manufacturers as $manufacturer){
        $status=$manufacturer->getStatus();    
        if($status==1){
?>
        <div class="manufacturer-img-box">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=".$manufacturer->getMenufecturerName() ?>">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setmanufacturerimage($manufacturer->getFilename())->setlegend($manufacturer->getLegend())->setTemplate('manufacturer/manufacturer_resize.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
        </a>
        </div>
<?php } 
} 
endif;
?>
```

Comment: You can show product_manufacturer.phtml and manufacturer/manufacturer block code?

Comment: You show all manufactures for autorisation dialer?

Comment: I dont think those are related to my question though. I just need to get rid of the title when there is no brand name set to the product.

Comment: If remove ` <?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') == "Bellazza" ` and check `$manufacturer->getMenufecturerName()` and if this empty you can don't show `<div class="manufacturer-name">`. p.s. sorry I bad speack English.

Comment: something like this? <?php elseif ($manufacturer->getMenufecturerName() == "" )?>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101723/discussion-between-dylan-daicy-siao-and-naumov).

Answer (score 0):

You need refactoring the code

```
 <div class="manufacturer">                                                          
        <div class="logoImg">
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('manufacturer/manufacturer')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('manufacturer/product_manufacturer.phtml')->toHtml();?>
        </div>
</div>
```

and check variable

```
 <?php if(!is_null($manufacturer->getMenufecturerName())): ?>
 <div class="manufacturer-name">
 <?php 
   echo Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')
   ->setAttribute(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
   ->load(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
   ->getIdByCode('catalog_product',"manufacturer")))
   ->getOptionText($manufacturer->getMenufecturerName())
 ?>
 </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

And you need refactoring your code. Because I loock much excess code in your template. You need get data in you block and in phtml you need render this data by API blocks. getImageSrc(); getManufactures() and more over methods for get processed information.